# trouble assigning id's to generated div in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my example : http://jsbin.com/hecohevegive/1/edit

i managed to draw the right images in place but i am having trouble assigning the right ID to each image especially when `i>0` if you hovered on the first image in the second row it give you `undefined` but in fact in the array there is a  title for this image wish is `(=angry)`

the code :

```
for (i = 0; i < RowCount; i++) {
    toAppend += "<tr>";
    for (j = 0; j < ColumnCount; j++) {
        toAppend += "<td><div class='emojiIcon' id='" + emojiShortCut[j][i] + "' title='" + emojiShortCut[j][i] + "' style='background-position: -" + j * size + "px -" + i * size + "px;' ></div></td>";
    }
    toAppend += "</tr>";
}
toAppend += "</table></div>";
return toAppend;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have all your IDs in a single row of the array. You need to make it a 2-dimensional array:

```
var emojiShortCut = [
    ["^-^", ">:(", "=(", "=@", "(y)", "(=note)", "(=journal)", "(=share)", "(=group)", "=)", "(=hsb)", "(=lfyel)", "(=lfgree)", "(=orange)", "(=apple)",],
    ["(=angry)", "(=sad)", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",],
    ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
];
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/rofovesonana/1/edit)